# how to show full value instead of dot in label Bullet in Column Charts amCharts

Tags: jquery, amcharts, amcharts4

I show the value in column but value show maximum 2 or 3 digit. i want to show all the value.
Hear my code:

```js
var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.label.text = "{visits}";
labelBullet.label.rotation = 270;
labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
labelBullet.label.verticalCenter = "middle";
labelBullet.label.fontSize = 10;
labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `labelBullet.label.truncate = false;`.